# How to retrieve an XHR response?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, chromium-embedded

Basically, I use Chromium to show a website on which I have no control. When the user clicks on a specific button, an XHR request is sent; and I would like to be able to retrieve the answer. So, let's say that the request sends A and the server replies with B; I would like to be able to read B. How can I do that?

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delphichromiumembedded/SKHuVjutSFE seemed to have the answer, but it works on DCEF only.
- I'm under the impression that making a descendant of TScheme would do the job, but I don't understand how it works...
- In my case, I cannot force DCEF to send a request. I really need to retrieve the value WHEN the user clicks on the specific button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Missing OnResourceResponse event

In a good old CEF1 you could simply use the `OnResourceResponse` event. In CEF3, such a seemingly trivial task might become a real challenge, because the [`Issue 515`](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issue/515) linked in [`the answer`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4828&p=8614#p8641) to the fundamentally same question as you're asking here is still opened and it seems the only way (at this time) is implementing your own [`CefResourceHandler`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefResourceHandler.html) handler to make a proxy between the browser and the *world outside*. The implementation principle is described in a [`similar topic`](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10794) like:

> You can use CefResourceHandler via
>   CefRequestHandler::GetResourceHandler and execute the request/return
>   the response contents yourself using CefURLRequest.

So here is what to do in DCEF3 (at this time):

### 1. Define your own resource handler

As first derive your own `TCefResourceHandlerOwn` descendant where implement at least the following methods:

- [`ProcessRequest`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefResourceHandler.html#ProcessRequest) - here you will *forward* (send) request A to the server and receive the server's response B (here's your first chance to work with the response data B), which you should keep stored (ideally in a class field, so that can be flushed to the output buffer of the `ReadResponse` method easily).
- [`GetResponseHeaders`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefResourceHandler.html#GetResponseHeaders) - in this method you'll need to fill the output parameters about the response B data length and (some of) the header fields (this might be the place where you will need to have your response B parsed for headers to fill the [`CefResponse`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefResponse.html) type parameter members).
- [`ReadResponse`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefResourceHandler.html#ReadResponse) - this is where you'll flush your response B data for final processing by the browser.

### 2. Assign your resource handler to the request

The next step is assigning your own resource handler to the request. That is technically as easy as returning a reference to the resource handler interface from the Chromium's [`OnGetResourceHandler`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRequestHandler.html#GetResourceHandler) event handler. But in this step you should consider that the more you narrow the criteria, the simpler you'll have live in your resource handler. Because if you assign your handler e.g. to any request (for any URL), then you may have to process and filter out responses coming in from servers that are absolutely unrelated to your overall task.

So, I would recommend to narrow the assignment deep down to the requests generated by that web application button, or at least by the request resource type (`RT_XHR` in this case), so you won't need to process all the requests by yourself.

### Code example

There are many ways how to implement the above steps. In this example I've interposed Chromium browser class and added there a new event `OnXmlHttpExchange` which fires when an XHR request completes (but before it's passed to the browser, which allows you to even modify the response).

```
uses
  CefLib, CefVCL;

type
  TXmlHttpExchangeEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; const Request: ICefRequest; const Response: ICefResponse; DataStream: TMemoryStream) of object;

  TChromium = class(CefVCL.TChromium)
  private
    FOnXmlHttpExchange: TXmlHttpExchangeEvent;
  protected
    procedure DoXmlHttpExchange(const Request: ICefRequest; const Response: ICefResponse; DataStream: TMemoryStream); virtual;
    function doOnGetResourceHandler(const Browser: ICefBrowser; const Frame: ICefFrame; const Request: ICefRequest): ICefResourceHandler; override;
  public
    property OnXmlHttpExchange: TXmlHttpExchangeEvent read FOnXmlHttpExchange write FOnXmlHttpExchange;
  end;

  TXmlHttpHandler = class(TCefResourceHandlerOwn)
  private
    FOwner: TChromium;
    FOffset: NativeUInt;
    FStream: TMemoryStream;
    FCallback: ICefCallback;
    FResponse: ICefResponse;
  protected
    function ProcessRequest(const Request: ICefRequest; const Callback: ICefCallback): Boolean; override;
    procedure GetResponseHeaders(const Response: ICefResponse; out ResponseLength: Int64; out RedirectUrl: ustring); override;
    function ReadResponse(const DataOut: Pointer; BytesToRead: Integer; var BytesRead: Integer; const Callback: ICefCallback): Boolean; override;
  public
    constructor Create(Owner: TChromium; const Browser: ICefBrowser; const Frame: ICefFrame; const SchemeName: ustring; const Request: ICefRequest); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure WriteResponse(const Request: ICefUrlRequest; Data: Pointer; Size: NativeUInt); virtual;
    procedure CompleteRequest(const Request: ICefUrlRequest); virtual;
  end;

  TXmlHttpRequestClient = class(TCefUrlrequestClientOwn)
  private
    FHandler: TXmlHttpHandler;
  protected
    procedure OnDownloadData(const Request: ICefUrlRequest; Data: Pointer; DataLength: NativeUInt); override;
    procedure OnRequestComplete(const Request: ICefUrlRequest); override;
  public
    constructor Create(Handler: TXmlHttpHandler); reintroduce;
  end;

implementation

{ TChromium }

procedure TChromium.DoXmlHttpExchange(const Request: ICefRequest; const Response: ICefResponse; DataStream: TMemoryStream);
begin
  // fire the OnXmlHttpExchange event
  if Assigned(FOnXmlHttpExchange) then
    FOnXmlHttpExchange(Self, Request, Response, DataStream);
end;

function TChromium.doOnGetResourceHandler(const Browser: ICefBrowser; const Frame: ICefFrame; const Request: ICefRequest): ICefResourceHandler;
begin
  // first trigger the browser's OnGetResourceHandler event
  Result := inherited;
  // if no handler was assigned and request is of type XHR, create our custom one
  if not Assigned(Result) and (Request.ResourceType = RT_XHR) then
    Result := TXmlHttpHandler.Create(Self, Browser, Frame, 'XhrIntercept', Request);
end;

{ TXmlHttpHandler }

constructor TXmlHttpHandler.Create(Owner: TChromium; const Browser: ICefBrowser; const Frame: ICefFrame; const SchemeName: ustring; const Request: ICefRequest);
begin
  inherited Create(Browser, Frame, SchemeName, Request);
  FOwner := Owner;
  FStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
end;

destructor TXmlHttpHandler.Destroy;
begin
  FStream.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TXmlHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(const Request: ICefRequest; const Callback: ICefCallback): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  // reset the offset value
  FOffset := 0;
  // store the callback reference
  FCallback := Callback;
  // create the URL request that will perform actual data exchange (you can replace
  // it with any other; e.g. with MSXML, or an Indy client)
  TCefUrlRequestRef.New(Request, TXmlHttpRequestClient.Create(Self));
end;

procedure TXmlHttpHandler.GetResponseHeaders(const Response: ICefResponse; out ResponseLength: Int64; out RedirectUrl: ustring);
var
  HeaderMap: ICefStringMultimap;
begin
  // return the size of the data we have in the response stream
  ResponseLength := FStream.Size;
  // fill the header fields from the response returned by the URL request
  Response.Status := FResponse.Status;
  Response.StatusText := FResponse.StatusText;
  Response.MimeType := FResponse.MimeType;
  // copy the header map from the response returned by the URL request
  HeaderMap := TCefStringMultimapOwn.Create;
  FResponse.GetHeaderMap(HeaderMap);
  if HeaderMap.Size <> 0 then
    FResponse.SetHeaderMap(HeaderMap);
end;

function TXmlHttpHandler.ReadResponse(const DataOut: Pointer; BytesToRead: Integer; var BytesRead: Integer; const Callback: ICefCallback): Boolean;
begin
  // since this method can be called multiple times (reading in chunks), check if we
  // have still something to transfer
  if FOffset < FStream.Size then
  begin
    Result := True;
    BytesRead := BytesToRead;
    // copy the data from the response stream to the browser buffer
    Move(Pointer(NativeUInt(FStream.Memory) + FOffset)^, DataOut^, BytesRead);
    // increment the offset by the amount of data we just copied
    Inc(FOffset, BytesRead);
  end
  else
    Result := False;
end;

procedure TXmlHttpHandler.WriteResponse(const Request: ICefUrlRequest; Data: Pointer; Size: NativeUInt);
begin
  // write the just downloaded data to the intermediate response stream
  FStream.Write(Data^, Size);
end;

procedure TXmlHttpHandler.CompleteRequest(const Request: ICefUrlRequest);
begin
  FStream.Position := 0;
  // store the response reference for the GetResponseHeaders method
  FResponse := Request.GetResponse;
  // this method is executed when the URL request completes, so we have everything we
  // need to trigger the OnXmlHttpExchange event
  FOwner.DoXmlHttpExchange(Request.GetRequest, FResponse, FStream);
  // this signals the handler that the request has completed and that it can process
  // the response headers and pass the content to the browser
  if Assigned(FCallback) then
    FCallback.Cont;
end;

{ TXmlHttpRequestClient }

constructor TXmlHttpRequestClient.Create(Handler: TXmlHttpHandler);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FHandler := Handler;
end;

procedure TXmlHttpRequestClient.OnDownloadData(const Request: ICefUrlRequest; Data: Pointer; DataLength: NativeUInt);
begin
  FHandler.WriteResponse(Request, Data, DataLength);
end;

procedure TXmlHttpRequestClient.OnRequestComplete(const Request: ICefUrlRequest);
begin
  FHandler.CompleteRequest(Request);
end;
```

And a possible usage of this interposed class:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Chromium: TChromium;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure XmlHttpExchange(Sender: TObject; const Request: ICefRequest; const Response: ICefResponse; DataStream: TMemoryStream);
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chromium.OnXmlHttpExchange := XmlHttpExchange;
end;

procedure TForm1.XmlHttpExchange(Sender: TObject; const Request: ICefRequest; const Response: ICefResponse; DataStream: TMemoryStream);
begin
  // here you can find the request for which you want to read the response (explore the
  // Request parameter members to see by what you can do this)
  if Request.Url = 'http://example.com' then
  begin
    // the DataStream stream contains the response, so process it here as you wish; you
    // can even modify it here if you want
    DataStream.SaveToFile(...);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: A simple XHR fiddle to play with you may find here http://jsfiddle.net/abkmqg7n/.